# Why are the before- and afterEach blocks called multiple times in unit-testing with Quick?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, quick-nimble

I wrote a test case with some example groups including `beforeEach` and `afterEach`.
And I expected that each `beforeEach` and `afterEach` would be called once for each `it`.

Alas, for a single `it` the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` got called multiple times.

I've looked at some documentation (i.e. Quick's own documentation and http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html), but those don't help my cause.

Here is a small snippet that demonstrates this:

class CheckerTests: QuickSpec {

```
override func spec() {

    describe("something") {
        beforeEach {
            tLog.info("describe before")
        }
        afterEach {
            tLog.info("describe after")
        }

        context("of something") {
            beforeEach {
                tLog.info("context before")
            }
            afterEach {
                tLog.info("context after")
            }

            it("should behave like something") {
                tLog.info("in the `IT`")
                expect(true).to(beTrue())
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

---

My console logs:

[image: Console logs before]

**The above logs raise two questions:**

- **I'm not sure *when* `beforeEach` and `afterEach` are called now; nor do I know why I see multiple logs calling them. How come they are called multiple times?**

<del>- **The above logs show that the `context`'s after block is called *before* the example passes...shouldn't that happen *after* the example?**</del>

From my code snippet I would've expect the logs to return:

[image: Console logs after]

Could someone explain what happens here? And is this the correct behaviour?

---

**EDIT:**

As suggested by a comment; I also added a log *inside* the `it` example (see the revised code snippet above).
Which gives me the following logs:

```
Test Suite 'CheckerTests' started at 2017-05-18 13:35:29.025
Test Case '-[CheckerTests something__of_something__should_behave_like_something]' started.
13:35:29.046  INFO CheckerTests.spec():21 - describe before
13:35:29.046  INFO CheckerTests.spec():21 - describe before
13:35:29.048  INFO CheckerTests.spec():29 - context before
13:35:29.048  INFO CheckerTests.spec():29 - context before
13:35:29.048  INFO CheckerTests.spec():36 - in the `IT`
13:35:29.048  INFO CheckerTests.spec():36 - in the `IT`
13:35:29.049  INFO CheckerTests.spec():32 - context after
1Test Case '-[CheckerTests something__of_something__should_behave_like_something]' passed (0.024 seconds).
3:35:29.049  INFO CheckerTests.spec():32 - context after
13:35:29.050  INFOTest Suite 'CheckerTests' passed at 2017-05-18 13:35:29.050.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.024 (0.025) seconds
 CheckerTests.spec():24 - describe after
13:35:29.050 \360\237\222Test Suite 'CheckerTests.xctest' passed at 2017-05-18 13:35:29.051.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.024 (0.026) seconds
\231 INFO CheckerTests.spec():24 - describe after
Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2017-05-18 13:35:29.051.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.024 (0.029) seconds
```

The above logs show me that the example is running twice, which confuses me even more.

---

**EDIT:**
One of the questions is answered:

<del>- **The above logs show that the `context`'s after block is called *before* the example passes...shouldn't that happen *after* the example?**</del>

*It seems the tests follow up in the correct order, so that answers the above question.*

---

**EDIT:**

For reference; this is what my Podfile looks like:

```
def pods_for_testing
    pod 'Quick'
    pod 'Nimble'
    pod 'KIF'
end

target 'Checker' do
  project 'Checker.xcodeproj', 'dev' => :debug, 'ntrl' => :debug, 'acpt' => :release, 'prod' => :release, 'prod appstore' => :release

  pod 'SQLCipher'
  pod 'UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK'
  pod 'TBXML', :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'SSZipArchive'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'Moya', '>= 8.0'
  pod 'Unbox'
  pod 'ProcedureKit'
  pod 'ProcedureKit/Mobile'
  pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
  pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
  pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'

  target 'CheckerTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      pods_for_testing
  end

  target 'CheckerUITests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      pods_for_testing
  end

end
```

Next to this I'm not sure what other settings could be affecting the tests.

Comment: If you add a `print("test print")` in the `it`, when does it print? The fact that the test library prints information about test pass after cleanup seems fine to me.

Comment: If I adjust the test with a print _inside_ the `it`, the print just gets printed twice as well. It just seems as if the `it` gets called twice or something.

Comment: So from this test and form your edit, we know that the methods get executed in the right order - the fact that the information that the test passed is printed after `context after` is irrelevant. Now, only problem that remains is the fact that the methods are executed twice.

Comment: I've updated the question; the fact remains that the example is executed multiple times...

Comment: Are you sure the method is executed twice and it's not just that a single log entry gets printed twice? Maybe add a variable counting the calls to a method?

Comment: @qwerty I'm quite sure the method runs by the log twice; added breakpoints too

Comment: It must have to do with how we add the Quick Framework to project. This `detail steps` might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44263733/3549695

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce the issue. But in my case, each of the testcase was being executed exactly one.

Thus, the issue doesn't seem to be reproducible in a normal setting. Probably you have some special setting that causes the issue you described above.

**Note:**  
I'm not sure what other libraries you have to get the 'tLog.info', but I couldn't find one. I assume that doesn't matter for this purpose. I substitute with print(_:) statement instead.

Here is my 'TryQuickTest.swift' looks like:

```
import XCTest
import Quick
import Nimble 

class TryQuickTest: QuickSpec {

    override func spec() {

        describe("blah") {
            beforeEach {
                print("describe before")
            }
            afterEach {
                print("describe after")
            }

            context("of blah2") {
                beforeEach {
                    print("context before")
                }
                afterEach {
                    print("context after")
                }

                it("first it should be like this") {
                    print("in the first `IT`")
                    XCTFail("Hey fail in first it")
                }

                it("second it should be like this") {
                    print("in the second `IT`")
                    XCTFail("Hey fail in second it")
                }
            }
        }   
    }    
}
```

And my console for the run of this test file:

```
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2017-05-28 07:35:32.345
Test Suite 'PlayQuickTests.xctest' started at 2017-05-28 07:35:32.347
Test Suite 'TryQuickTest' started at 2017-05-28 07:35:32.348
Test Case '-[PlayQuickTests.TryQuickTest blah__of_blah2__first_it_should_be_like_this]' started.
describe before
context before
in the first `IT`
/Users/shisui/Developer/General/iOS_Swift/PlayQuick/PlayQuickTests/TryQuickTest.swift:35: error: -[PlayQuickTests.TryQuickTest blah__of_blah2__first_it_should_be_like_this] : failed - Hey fail in first it
context after
describe after
Test Case '-[PlayQuickTests.TryQuickTest blah__of_blah2__first_it_should_be_like_this]' failed (0.004 seconds).
Test Case '-[PlayQuickTests.TryQuickTest blah__of_blah2__second_it_should_be_like_this]' started.
describe before
context before
in the second `IT`
/Users/shisui/Developer/General/iOS_Swift/PlayQuick/PlayQuickTests/TryQuickTest.swift:40: error: -[PlayQuickTests.TryQuickTest blah__of_blah2__second_it_should_be_like_this] : failed - Hey fail in second it
context after
describe after
Test Case '-[PlayQuickTests.TryQuickTest blah__of_blah2__second_it_should_be_like_this]' failed (0.003 seconds).
Test Suite 'TryQuickTest' failed at 2017-05-28 07:35:32.359.
    Executed 2 tests, with 2 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.007 (0.010) seconds
Test Suite 'PlayQuickTests.xctest' failed at 2017-05-28 07:35:32.359.
    Executed 2 tests, with 2 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.007 (0.012) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' failed at 2017-05-28 07:35:32.374.
    Executed 2 tests, with 2 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.007 (0.029) seconds
```

From the output above. The each testcase was executed only once.

And if I remove the second 'it' part. The console output would look like this:

```
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2017-05-28 07:56:09.214
Test Suite 'PlayQuickTests.xctest' started at 2017-05-28 07:56:09.215
Test Suite 'TryQuickTest' started at 2017-05-28 07:56:09.215
Test Case '-[PlayQuickTests.TryQuickTest blah__of_blah2__first_it_should_be_like_this]' started.
describe before
context before
in the first `IT`
/Users/shisui/Developer/General/iOS_Swift/PlayQuick/PlayQuickTests/TryQuickTest.swift:35: error: -[PlayQuickTests.TryQuickTest blah__of_blah2__first_it_should_be_like_this] : failed - Hey fail in first it
context after
describe after
Test Case '-[PlayQuickTests.TryQuickTest blah__of_blah2__first_it_should_be_like_this]' failed (0.006 seconds).
Test Suite 'TryQuickTest' failed at 2017-05-28 07:56:09.222.
    Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.006 (0.007) seconds
Test Suite 'PlayQuickTests.xctest' failed at 2017-05-28 07:56:09.224.
    Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.006 (0.009) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' failed at 2017-05-28 07:56:09.224.
    Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.006 (0.011) seconds
```

Comment: I would suggest to create a new project from scratch and add the Quick framework again. Maybe it has to do with some special settings.

Comment: Created a new project and tried again; the first time had the same problem, the second time I got the correct output. I really don't know why though.

I'm not sure _what_ special settings I could have in my Tests (in the original project), I used the same pods and configuration.

Comment: Oh and for reference; the `tLog` is just my 'test-logger', an instance of `SwiftyBeaver`

Comment: Ah, just read the notice. Well truth to be told, I've still got no clue why it happens. However letting the bounty 'go to waste' is also...a waste :)

Comment: Thanks for being thoughtful.  Probably next time you could provide more context on how the issue occurred.  It also took me several frustrating attempts to make have a working project with the Quick test framework. Not a trivial task. So many things could go wrong.  I wish there's a standard / automatic way to set it up. Nonesuch could we found today.

Comment: FYI. I bounce a new question in SO about how to reliably set up quick test framework on Xcode. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44244912/3549695